# Action bar not show good in android lower than 4

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, fullscreen, android-appcompat

My Action Bar is not showing properly.
I used support library appcompact v7. Application is running well but
when I run it on Android lower version as 4 then 
is my Action Bar outspread to full screen so it overlay of the
main view.

Do you have some suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks

Illustrative pictures:

on Android 4

[image: on Android 4]

older versions

[image: older versions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a couple of days I found a solution to this problem.

First, I had the following lines in my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
```

This is okay, but I had also inserted this line

```
compile fileTree('libs')
```

in the gradle file to add adMob library to my application, and this caused the problem.

In the libs folder of my project, I had also added 'android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'. Action Bar used this first, without the dependencies that are contained in res folder of the appcompat library.

I deleted 'android-support-v7-appcompat.jar' from libs folder of my application project and my application is now fully functional on Android API 7-18 without using third party solutions, such as Sherlock.

Comment: I have similar problem can't understand how you resolved it ?

Answer (score 0):

The Action bar doesn't show in devices running older versions of android. It doesn't matter that you are using the compatibility lib.

If you want the action bar on older android devices , I would recommend Action Bar Sherlock . Here is the link to it http://actionbarsherlock.com

Also I didn't quite follow you last sentence , are you saying that the action bar is expanding to full screen in older devices? That is very unusual , can you post your code pls.

Comment: Thanks @DrkStr for answer. For clarification, my action bar is running on older version android but not correctly. Action bar is expanding to full screen in older devices, as you said. I don't know why you said that it doesn't matter on compatibility lib when on this android dveloper site: [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding) is indicated that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarCompat is not supported in API level 4. It is only supported from API level 7. Have a look: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: Yes, I know it and I fully agree. I didn't use API level 4 in my application. I want use Action Bar with API 7 and newer.

Comment: It seems like your usage of ActionBarCompat is not correct. Have you followed the below link to add ActionBarCompat to your project? http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: I did do exactly what is decsribed in that documentation. But my prolem is always remained. Yet I'll try run android sdk samples and perhaps I'll discover some solution.